# How can I do a LIKE query using an association?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Using ActiveRecord, how can I do a `LIKE` query based on a property of an association? Specifically, I'm looking for something that works with polymorphic associations.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :private_note, class_name: '::Note', as: :noteable,
    conditions: {label: 'private'}
  has_one :public_note,  class_name: '::Note', as: :noteable,
    conditions: {label: 'public'}
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :noteable, polymorphic: true
  validates :content,   :presence: true
end
```

I want to find invoices whose `private_note` has a `content` column containing the word "friendly".

Answer (score 0):

## Use #merge

This can be accomplished with the `.merge` method.

```
 Invoice.joins(:private_note).merge(Note.where("content LIKE ?", '%friendly%'))
```